# What is the use case for a Cypress Dashboard User?

Tags: cypress

Cypress does End to End testing.  And I hear good things about it.

As I look at the pricing model, I see that you can get 20 users of the dashboard for $4,788 per year.  My company has 100 developers that will at times be needing to write End To End tests for their projects.  That comes to $47,880 per year.

$50K is too much for me to ask my boss for when there are so many open source options out there (ie Jest + Puppet).

But I noticed that they indicate that the Cypress Test Runner is free and Open Source.  So I am confused now.

Can one get by with just the test runner?  Or is that more like saying it is free for your build server?  Does everyone who authors End to End tests end up using the Cypress Dashboard?

**What is the difference between using the Cypress Test Runner and the Cypress Dashboard?**

Comment: You can use the test runner for free without any restrictions. When using the Dashboard Service, every Testrun is sent to Cypress. There you have a very nice page to analyze failed tests. E.g. you can access the screenshots and videos without any effort. Please see this: https://dashboard.cypress.io/projects/jhrbm1/runs (should be visible for anonymous users, too, I think). If you open a test run, you see something like this: https://imgur.com/hB4qwko In the right bottom area you have three buttons. One to get the results, one for the screenshots, one for the videos.

Comment: Another example of one of my public projects: https://dashboard.cypress.io/projects/rmxq4a/runs (Cypress has also public projects, but I do not know the URLS, so sorry for those examples)

Comment: If you use the dashboard, cypress can automatically let your tests run on your CI on multiple machines, based on the data it has fetched from previous runs. So they can decide which tests should run in parallel to get the fastest test runs. Also you have the nice UI without any own setup. And you can e.g. tag your test runs and see easily in the dashboar which tests runs on which environment (OS, Browser, mobile or not and so on). Not sure if there are other advantages. We at work use the free runner. But I know another company in town that use the dashboard and are very happy with it

Comment: tl;dr; Cypress Testrunner is free for commercial projects, too. Dashboard Service gives you some benefits that may or may not be relevant for you.